# How can we get the view result model of view component

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I can invoke a view component using `Component.InvokeAsync` but I want to get only the model of view component not the rendered HTML.

```
public class MyComponent : ViewComponent {
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(){
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

How can I call MyComponent from controller and get the viewModel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have directory used `MyComponent` in the controller and got the viewModel

`MyComponent.InvokeAsync`